# Changing desktop wallpaper with a batch script only works some of the time

Tags: batch, windows-registry, desktop

I'm using a batch script to change the desktop background. I'm using a test script to just do this one component which will later be become a part of a more involved script. The test script has the following

```
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d "" /f
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d "C:\Users\username\Pictures\mypic.PNG" /f
RUNDLL32.EXE user32.dll, UpdatePerUserSystemParameters
```

This works as expected (refreshing instantly or after a sign out/sign in) and sometimes there is no change. I have also tried with .bmp files and have the same inconsistency. Any ideas why?

Comment: 1. Are you always running it as Admin? 2. Does the full path to an image contain spaces that need to be escaped?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I am running as Admin and there are no spaces in the path

Comment: https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2019/06/changewallpaper.html is a wallpaper changer for batch files.